# C++11 virtual copy constructor

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++11, copy-constructor

I'm reading C++ Design Patterns and Derivatives Pricing by Mark Joshi and implementing his code in C++11.  Everything has gone pretty well until I hit chapter 4 where he discusses virtual copy constructors.

```
PayOffDoubleDigital thePayOff(Low, Up);
VanillaOption theOption(thePayOff, Expiry);
```

The problem here is that `VanillaOption` contains a reference to `thePayOff`.  If that's the case and someone modifies `thePayOff`, the the behavior of `theOption` could be modified unwittingly.  The solution he advises is to create a virtual copy constructor in `PayOffDoubleDigital`'s base class, `PayOff` so that `theOption` contains its own copy:

```
virtual PayOff* clone() const = 0;
```

and then defined in each inherited class:

```
PayOff* PayOffCall::clone() const
{
    return new PayOffCall(*this);
}
```

Returning new caught me as something that might be inappropriate in C++11.  So what is the proper way of handling this using C++11?

Comment: Rule of zero: make a handle class with the proper ownership semantics and use that everywhere.

Comment: Looks like I have some additional research.  Thank you Martinho.

Comment: I wrote about it before: http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/08/15/rule-of-zero.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> The solution he advises is to create a virtual copy constructor in PayOffDoubleDigital's base class [...]

First of all, `clone()` is not a copy-constructor. A copy constructor for class `X` is a special member function with no return type which usually has the signature:

```
X(X const&)
```

And *may* have the signature:

```
X(X&)
```

Function `clone()` is just a regular (virtual) function, and its particular meaning is recognized by you - the user - as something which creates clones of your object, but not by the compiler, which has no idea what `clone()` does.

> Returning new caught me as something that might be inappropriate in C++11

That's true, using `new` is not idiomatic in C++11. In fact, in C++11 you should (almost) never use `new` unless you are doing really low-level memory management (something you should avoid unless you *really* have to) - and in C++14, you can remove the "almost". Unfortunately, this is likely the exceptional case where `new` is needed.

I'm saying this because I believe returning a `unique_ptr` sounds like the appropriate thing to do here (the option object has to hold its own `PayOff` object, and that must stay alive just as long as the option object is alive), and there is no `std::make_unique()` function in C++11 (it will be there in C++14):

```
std::unique_ptr<PayOff> PayOffCall::clone() const
{
    return std::unique_ptr<PayOff>(new PayOffCall(*this));
}
```

Having `VanillaOption` (or its base class) hold a `unique_ptr` rather than a raw pointer would make it unnecessary to `delete` the `PayOff` object returned by `clone()`. In turn, not having to `delete` that object means no need to define a user-provided destructor, and no need to take care about the [*Rule of Three*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), [*Rule of Five*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11), or whatnot.

Whenever you can, follow [R. Martinho's Fernandes's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16793835/c11-virtual-copy-constructor/16794105#comment24201666_16793835) and go for the [**Rule of Zero**](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/).

Comment: Thank you for the well thought response.  This is an area of C++ that has been difficult to master for me.  I would mark this up if I could.  But, this being my first question, I don't have the necessary reputation.  Need more people to mark up the question :)

Comment: @BDig: Don't worry, keep asking good questions and you will soon get the rep :) Glad I could help, and good luck with your book

Answer (score 1):

As often when dealing with ownership, the cleanest solution is to return a smart pointer: it both guarantees exception safety (no risk of memory leak) and makes it clear by whom the objects are owned.

Whether you'll want to use `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` depends entirely on you.